# Core Data how to avoid additional entity?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, core-data, entity-relationship

Simple question: I have a many-to-many relationship between sales reps and contacts:

```
SalesRep <<---------------->> Contact
```

For each contact, each sales rep can specify if he is a favorite (`BOOL isFavorite`) and keep some notes (`NSString *notes`).

The way this is currently modeled is with an interim entity:

```
SalesRep <------>> Relationship <<-------> Contact
```

where the additional information is kept in two attributes of the Relationship entity.

Is there a way around the new Relationship entity, just modeling this with additional attributes? How about if the notes field is omitted? Is there maybe a solution with parent / child entities?

Comment: You've modelled it correctly, as far as I'm concerned. Is there any reason why you're looking for a different solution?

Comment: I want to simplify. How about, if the notes field does not exist? It seems a bit much to create an entity just for a single bit flag.

Comment: the idea is good as relationships might get more complicated in the future.

Comment: Exactly. I think you're already at the cleanest solution, which will easily allow you to store more information about the relationship should you need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there is no real opportunity for simplification.
This is viewed as the *cleanest* solution.

Thanks guys.